# Flutter: Different ListView ItemBuilder layouts based on Network image dimensions

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a news reader app using Flutter. However, the challenge I am facing is that I need to show different layouts based on the dimensions of the network image. I researched around this and couldn't find a solution. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I somehow made a workaround not using the listview and using the singlechildscrollview in horizontal direction and list of row widgets.
Just check out the example that I have made :
I have taken the JSON data locally using the list of network images.

below is my local JSON(parse.json):

```
{
    "apus_findgo_gallery_images": {
        "2092": "http://www.camhalalguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/6b806c88-2f19-4054-914b-dee3c0c091eb.jpg",
        "2093": "http://www.camhalalguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/24.1.1-phnom-chisor-temple.jpg",
        "2096": "http://www.camhalalguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/image-asset.jpg",
        "2098": "http://www.camhalalguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/phnom-chisor-01-600_orig.jpg",
        "2099": "http://www.camhalalguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/phnom-chisor-02-600_orig.jpg",
        "2100": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg",
        "2101":"https://images.ctfassets.net/4kwp3o37mlek/26EyWHHgDOS4qSCCmAWYuY/e4fd2b3c2054b06fafe7ddebca47d1a8/Apple_Logo.png",
        "2102":"https://img.helpnetsecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/09195727/1450275992_key-100x100.png",
        "2103":"https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/282828/eae0d0/?retina=1",
        "2104":"https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/600x200.jpg"
    }
}
```

Below is the model class i have made :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final yourModelClass = yourModelClassFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

YourModelClass yourModelClassFromJson(String str) => YourModelClass.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String yourModelClassToJson(YourModelClass data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class YourModelClass {
    Map<String, String> apusFindgoGalleryImages;

    YourModelClass({
        this.apusFindgoGalleryImages,
    });

    factory YourModelClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => YourModelClass(
        apusFindgoGalleryImages: Map.from(json["apus_findgo_gallery_images"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, String>(k, v)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "apus_findgo_gallery_images": Map.from(apusFindgoGalleryImages).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
    };
}
```

This is the main class that ia have made :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/model.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> imagesList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    yourMethod();
  }

  yourMethod() async {
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final yourModelClass = yourModelClassFromJson(jsonString);

    Map data = yourModelClass.apusFindgoGalleryImages;
    List<String> list = new List();

    data.forEach((key, value) {
      list.add(value);
    });
    imagesList = list;

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  Widget ImageCard(String data) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.97,
        child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Image.network(
                    data,
                    loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                        ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                              ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                  loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                              : null,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImageCards(List<String> product) {
    final cards = <Widget>[];
    Widget imageCards;

    if (product.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        cards.add(ImageCard(product[i]));
        print(product.length);
      }
      imageCards = Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(children: cards),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      imageCards = Container();
    }
    return imageCards;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildImageCards(imagesList),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the response. However, I was looking for a solution to have different layouts based on the dimensions of the network image.

Comment: can you brief different layouts based on dimensions.