# How to set the height of widgets in grid view builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a list view builder. Inside the list view builder there is grid view builder. It works fine. But above the last image there is unwanted space is generating. I tried with fit:Boxfit.fill in image widget, but it making the picture pixelating. Is there any way to build row or columns dynamically in flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  var data, localData, innerData, count, imageUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo Grid")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          localData = data[index];
          count = localData["column"];

          innerData = localData["data"];

          return GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: count,
            ),
            itemCount: innerData == null ? 0 : innerData.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              imageUrl = innerData[index]["imageUrl"];

              // return Container(
              //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //     image: DecorationImage(
              //       image: NetworkImage(
              //         imageUrl,
              //       ),
              //     ),
              //   ),
              // );

              return Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Image.network(imageUrl),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
 Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    final newEndPoint = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/asy4s";
    final oldEndPoint = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fea5o";
    final response = await http.get(newEndPoint);

    final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      data = parsedJson;
    });
  }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgqi3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image in an Aspect Ratio Widget with aspect Ratio of 16/9

```
return Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: AspectRatio( aspectRatio: 16 / 9, child: Image.network(imageUrl)),
              );
```

Comment: Hi @p2hari, thanks for answering my question. Is not working.

Comment: I just saw that the SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount takes a childAspect Ratio, could you try that

Answer (score 0):

Just check the below-mentioned link where if have given the example, where if have created dynamically the widgets and the added. just check the example, maybe it will help you out :

[Flutter: Different ListView ItemBuilder layouts based on Network image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390468/flutter-different-listview-itembuilder-layouts-based-on-network-image-dimension/60392403?noredirect=1#comment106863498_60392403)

Comment: Hi @sagar acharya, thanks for answering my question. I will check the link.